# Javascript Hide/Show multiple elements

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid, display

my code isn't working:

JS:

```
function openform_1() {
var a = document.getElementById("2");

if (a.style.display === "inline") {
document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("form_1_b").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("2").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("3").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("4").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("5").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("6").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("7").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("8").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("9").style.display = ("none");
}
if (a.style.display === "none") {
document.getElementById("form_1").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("form_1_b").style.display = ("none");
document.getElementById("2").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("3").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("4").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("5").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("6").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("7").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("8").style.display = ("inline");
document.getElementById("9").style.display = ("inline");    
}}
```

HTML:

```
    <img src="img/edit.png" width="15" height="15" class="edit"id="1" onclick="openform_1()">    
    <img src="img/edit.png" width="15" height="15" class="edit" id="2" onclick="openform_2()">
    ...
```

CSS:

```
.edit {display: inline;}
```

When I'm clicking on the image with the id "1" nothing happens. What I want it to happen is that all elements with the id from 2-9 disappear and the elements with the id "form_1" and "form_1_b" appear.
Clicking "1" again should restore everything.

edit:

```
function openform_2() {
var a = document.getElementById("1");

if (a.style.display === "inline") {
document.getElementById("form_2").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("form_2_b").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("1").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("3").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("4").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("5").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("6").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("7").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("8").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("9").style.display = "none";
}
if (a.style.display === "none") {
document.getElementById("form_2").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("form_2_b").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("1").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("3").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("4").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("5").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("6").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("7").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("8").style.display = "inline";
document.getElementById("9").style.display = "inline";  
}}
```

This is how it looks like in the browser:

[image: This is what it looks like]

Clicked:

[image]

This is how it should look like when I click one time.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should think DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `else if` on the second `if` statement.

If it isn't an `else if` then it would say does it equal `inline`? Then set it to `none`. Does it equal `none`? Yes it does because it just changed it to it, so change it back to `inline`.
`Else if` means it won't do it if the first `if` is `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider replacing ('inline') with "inline". 
Removes the quotes.

For example:
**document.getElementById("3").style.display = "inline";**

You made classic repetitive errors.